# Disabling parent page when child page is loaded

Tags: asp.net, javascript, jquery

I have to disable our parent page(Complete gray out and non functioning) when child page is loaded. Once I close child page then I could perform any action at my parent page.

I can not use Div at my parent page because it may be many page so i have to controlled it from child page only.

Please help me at this issue and suggest me some link or code snippet.

Comment: What do you mean by "child" and "parent" page here. Iframes?

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your problem *exactly*, but if you want to disable elements or anything except an element, it seems that the blockUI plugin is exactly what you're after, [check it out here](http://jquery.malsup.com/block/).

[Check out the demos here](http://jquery.malsup.com/block/#demos)

Comment: ok I make it more clear. I have some link on page on clicking that one pop up page is opened.The popup page(child) is of some other domain.when that pop up(child) page will be open then parent page should be disable and once i close it parent page should become live.

Answer (score 0):

if by child and parent, you mean to open a new window, then you might want to check the jquery ui dialog plugin. http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/

It can be used the way you want by setting the modal property true